# I am new to Apache Flink and getting error FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] at in_streaming_mode() The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: apache-flink, pyflink

I am just running a simple code, and installed java 21 as well, using flink version 1.19.0

```
from pyflink.table import   EnvironmentSettings,TableEnvironment

setting = EnvironmentSettings.in_streaming_mode()
table_env = TableEnvironment.create(environment_settings=setting)

country_dict = {"1":"canda","2":"India"}
schema = ["id","country"]

table = table_env.from_elements(country_dict,schema=schema)

if __name__=="__main__"
    print(table.get_schema())
    print(table.execute())
```

getting error at line 2, in_streaming_mode().

I tried to uninstall and install again, tried to search online but not getting any result.

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\91889\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\pyflink\table\environment_settings.py", line 229, in 
in_streaming_mode
    return EnvironmentSettings.new_instance().in_streaming_mode().build()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\91889\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\pyflink\table\environment_settings.py", line 196, in 
new_instance
    return EnvironmentSettings.Builder()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\91889\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\pyflink\table\environment_settings.py", line 53, in __init__
    gateway = get_gateway()
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\91889\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\pyflink\java_gateway.py", line 64, in get_gateway    
    _gateway = launch_gateway()
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\91889\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\pyflink\java_gateway.py", line 110, in launch_gateway    p = launch_gateway_server_process(env, args)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\91889\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\pyflink\pyflink_gateway_server.py", line 315, in launch_gateway_server_process
    return Popen(list(filter(lambda c: len(c) != 0, command)),
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1024, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1509, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```